# Add controls dynamically in flowlayoutpanel

Tags: c#, winforms, dynamic-controls, flowlayoutpanel

In a windows form, I can add control dynamically by doing this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    Button button = new Button();
    button.Location = new Point(160, 30 * i + 10);

    button.Tag = i;
    this.Controls.Add(button);
}
```

How do I add controls dynamically in a `FlowLayoutPanel`?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

For a [FlowLayoutPanel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.flowlayoutpanel?view=netcore-3.1), you don't need to specify a `.Location` since the controls are arranged for you:

> Represents a panel that dynamically lays out its contents horizontally
> or vertically. ... The FlowLayoutPanel control arranges its contents
> in a horizontal or vertical flow direction. Its contents can be
> wrapped from one row to the next, or from one column to the next.

Just change "`flowLayoutPanel1`" to the name of your `FlowLayoutPanel`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    Button button = new Button();
    button.Tag = i;
    flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(button);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make items flow dynamically from database(sql server) to flowLayoutPanel1 :

```
 void button1_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button btn = sender as Button;
        btn.BackColor = Color.Gold;
    }

void button1_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button btn = sender as Button;
        btn.BackColor = Color.Green;
    }


private void form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Clear();
        SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(@"server=.;database=MyDatabase;integrated security=true");

        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from Items order by ItemsName", cn);

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);

        for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            Button btn = new Button();
            btn.Name = "btn" + dt.Rows[i][1];
            btn.Tag = dt.Rows[i][1];
            btn.Text = dt.Rows[i][2].ToString();
            btn.Font = new Font("Arial", 14f, FontStyle.Bold);
            // btn.UseCompatibleTextRendering = true;
            btn.BackColor = Color.Green;
            btn.Height = 57;
            btn.Width = 116;
            btn.Click += button1_Click;   //  set any method
            btn.Enter += button1_Enter;   // 
            btn.Leave += button1_Leave;   //


            flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(btn);                

        }
```

Comment: What on earth does SQL have to do with this question?

Comment: Helped me as I am adding controls to a form from a database