# Multiple panels with different content visual studio

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I'm currently learning visual studio and i have this curiousity. How to make a multiple panels with different content? I mean for example in facebook timeline if i post a picture/words and then a panel will created and the content of that panel is my posted picture/words. I'm thinking that this is like a kind of a loop that if i posted something a new panel will created. But i don't know to do this.

Comment: Hello, welcome to the site.  What have you got for code so far?  Are you looking to do [something like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16900522/add-controls-dynamically-in-flowlayoutpanel)?

Comment: If you want to repeat a layout such as with the "panels" on facebook, you probably want to look into creating a user control

Comment: You can add several panels with different controls in design view. On the View menu choose Other Windows -> Document Outline to easily switch from Panel to Panel and plan the layout.

Comment: First we need to know, what project are you building? Wpf or winform?

Comment: Winform in visual studio