# How to create a winforms equivaelent control to inline-flexbox

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, button, inline

Is it possible to create an Inline-flexbox equivalent in .NET Winforms that is driven by various Combobox and Checkbox Controls on a Windows form?
I dont need something too sophisticated, perhaps 6 at most of these buttons with curved edges that just stack inline as they are added and sized to the text within the button.

[this is an example you can add many of these filters and remove them by clicking the X](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mwcZZ.png)

Comment: Did you take a look at `FlowLayoutPanel`? `FlowLayoutPanel` can be used to stack controls one after another, the alignment is done by the control itself.

Comment: Thanx will take a look now. Needs to be able to add or remove controls without a fixed order. I just found this post on Stack overflow "Add controls dynamically in flowlayoutpanel" ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16900522/add-controls-dynamically-in-flowlayoutpanel

Answer (score 0):

This is from the hyperlink and inserts dynamically controls hence does what I need you helped a great deal sideways. Shouldn't we be using tabs instead of spaces as it causes problem in code?

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
Button button = new Button();
button.Tag = i;
flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(button);
}
```

Comment: Glad you solved it! If you paste the code in your IDE, it normally handles all the text alignment for you, so it should insert tabs. But even if not, C# code is not sensitive to tabs or spaces as, for example, YAML.